# Как функции вернуть ответ на AJAX-запрос?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как сделать чтобы getData() возвращала не undefined, а содержимое строки 36?
[image: Как сделать чтобы getData() возвращала не undefined, а содержимое строки 36?]

Comment: Уберите const у xhr, var getData вместо const

Comment: Что даст смена типа переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поскольку вы используете асинхронный запрос то код после запроса продолжает выполняться, а функция не успевает возвращать значение, можно использовать функцию callback :
в функцию getData(callback) отправляете функцию callback

```
function returnData(data){
console.log(data);
}

getData(returnData){
// формирование запроса
if(this.readyState ==4 &&this.status == 200){
 returnData(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
}
}
```

Comment: Пробовал такой каллбек, в консоль ничего не выводит. 
Комментарии убирают табуляцию из кода, поэтому ссылка на кодпен: https://codepen.io/beast1/pen/KQZZjR

Comment: Как оказалось ничего он не выводил из-за того что я сделал xhr.onreadystatechange через стрелочную функцию. Когда заменил обратно на обычную всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
// далее в цикле получить значения 
// или вывести в консоль, например name
console.log(response.name)
```

Comment: Способ записывает ответ внутри области видимости анонимной функции, а мне нужна возможность получить доступ к данным из ответа внутри любой области видимости.

Comment: я Вам показал как вообще что-либо вывести в консоль из ответа сервера. У Вас же до этого было просто undifined

Comment: Что Вам стоит сделать return response.name? Или собрать всё в строку и опять же, через return.